# How i can group rows use phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm developing a project by PHP with librarais `PHPEXCEL`

My probleme is how i can group rows in excel by `PHPEXCEL`, as picture below

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "group rows"? Do you mean merging the cells?

Comment: [Group/Outline a Row](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#showhide-a-row) straight from the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation)